# Get object with string identifier

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties, identifier

I need help with getting property of object with String in JS.

I have object

```
elements = {
    element : {
            date: {
                 day: 'Monday'
            }
    }
}
```

and i have JS function where input is **"element.date.day"**. And
basically i need  to do something like this:

```
function getObjectByStringIdentifier ( stringId ) {
    return elements[stringId];
}
```

is this possible in JS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
var elements = {
  element: {
    date: {
      day: 'Monday'
    },
    example: {
      abc: 'hii'
    }
  }
};

function getObjectByStringIdentifier(stringId) {
  stringId = stringId.split('.');
  // split string using `.`
  var res = elements;
  // define res as object
  for (var i = 0; i < stringId.length; i++)
  // iterate over array
    res = res[stringId[i]]
    // update res as inner object value
  return res;
  // return result
}

console.log(getObjectByStringIdentifier("element.date.day"));
console.log(getObjectByStringIdentifier("element.example.abc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
var elements = {
    element : {
            date: {
                 day: 'Monday'
            }
    },
    cars : {
        racing : "Lamborghini",
        classic: "Rolls Royce"  
    }
}


function getObjectByStringIdentifier ( stringId ) {
    objects = stringId.split(".");
    element = elements; 
    for(i=0; i < objects.length; i++)
        element = element[objects[i]]; 
    return element;
}

alert(getObjectByStringIdentifier("cars.racing"));
alert(getObjectByStringIdentifier("element.date.day"));
alert(getObjectByStringIdentifier("cars.classic"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes **you** can ! :-)

```js
var elements = {
    element : {
            date: {
                 day: 'Monday'
            }
    }
}

function getObjectByStringIdentifier ( stringId ) {
    
    //return elements[stringId];
    //            ^      ^  
    //            |      |  
    //            |------|---------------------------------------------|  
    //                   |                                             |
    //        -----------|                                             | 
    //        |                                                        |
    //        °                                                        °
    return stringId.split('.').reduce(function(t,v){return t[v]; } , elements)
}


/** let's test it now ! **/

var stringIdentifier = "element.date.day";
var result = getObjectByStringIdentifier( stringIdentifier );


document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id='el'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modern browsers support JSON.parse().

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

In browsers that don't, you can include the json2 library.

```
alert(arr_from_json.elements);
```

Comment: have you tried what you suggest ? this don't do what OP need !